# issue with create function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function

I am trying to get year from orderdate function

type
orderdate date

```
create or replace function getyearfromdate(year date)returns 
table 
as
$$
begin
    return QUERY execute (
         'select extract (year from orderdate) FROM public.orderalbum'
    );
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

I write a logic but not able to create a function

I want to return year from the orderdate.

I want to pass a orderdate and return year from the function

I am facing below error

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
> LINE 3: as
>         ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 70
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems you only want a wrapper around the `extract()` function. In that case you do not want a set returning function. And you don't need PL/pgSQL or even dynamic SQL for this:

```
create or replace function getyearfromdate(p_date_value date)
  returns int --<< make this a scalar function!
as
$$
  select extract(year from p_date_value)::int;
$$
language sql;
```

Note that I renamed your parameter as I find a parameter named `year` for a `date` value highly confusing.

That function can then be used as part of a SELECT list:

```
SELECT ..., getyearfromdate(orderdate)
FROM public.orderalbum
GROUP BY ...
```

---

Original answer based on the question before comments clarified it.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) `returns table` requires a table definition.

Your use of dynamic SQL is also useless.

```
create or replace function getyearfromdate(year date)
  returns table (year_of_month int)
as
$$
begin
    return QUERY 
      select extract(year from orderdate)::int 
      FROM public.orderalbum;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

I am not sure why you are passing a parameter to the function that you never use.

Comment: No need for plpgsql either, sql is good enough. A view would also solve the problem

Comment: @FrankHeikens: I know, but I fear that would confuse Rahul Patil even more...

Comment: I'm aware of your skills and knowledge, my comment is actually for Rahul

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to get year from orderdate that is the reason see below query ```NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(albumid) as Album,getyearFromDate(year) as x FROM public.orderAlbum GROUP BY getyearFromDate(year)", conn);```

Comment: Then it seems you do not want a table function at all.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name then what should i try please suggest

Comment: @FrankHeikens view can pass select statement in postgresqlcommand

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you got it i want to return date from orderdate thank you

Comment: Then pass it: `getyearfromdate(orderdate)`

Comment: This makes the function getyearfromdate() just an alias for EXTRACT() with a hardcoded "field" for year.

Comment: @FrankHeikens yes - I mentioned that in my first sentence. I assume(!) this is part of a migration from a different DBMS product that doesn't support `extract()` and they might already have such a function and don't want to switch to the standard compliant EXTRACT function

Comment: You could also make this one immutable for some (minor) performance improvements