# how to get month only from current year

Tags: postgresql

I am working with postgresql

I am trying to get every month from current year

see postgres date image

[image]

current all month are get see below script and image

```
 select extract(month from orderdate) 
      FROM public.orderalbum;
```

[image]

see my code in c# side

```
     //month wise sale
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult getmonthSales()
    {
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(albumid) as albumid, getmonthfromdate(orderdate) as y FROM public.orderAlbum GROUP BY getmonthfromdate(orderdate)", conn);
```

please see my above select query I pass a function in select query

I want to show every date from current year

```
create or replace function getyearfromdate(year date)
  returns table (orderdate int)
as
$$
begin
    return QUERY 
      select extract(year from orderdate)::int 
      FROM public.orderalbum;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

I want to show every month from current year

Comment: Using a set returning function is wrong as I have [explained in my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74768467/330315) you need to use the function that returns an integer. The correct usage is also in that answer that you have already accepted

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok but what is logic for that get everymonth from currentyear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    extract(month FROM t.dt) AS yr_month,
    extract(year from t.dt) as yr
FROM (
    VALUES ('2022-12-14'::date),
        ('2022-01-30'::date),
        ('2021-06-14'::date)) AS t (dt)
WHERE
    extract(year FROM t.dt) = 2022;

 yr_month |  yr  
----------+------
       12 | 2022
        1 | 2022
```